# Resource for learning the Beis Yosef

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tur

Does anyone know of a book or website that is dedicated to understanding/explaining the Beis Yosef on the Tur? (In a similar way as the Pri Megadim works on the Taz/SHach/Magen Avraham).

Comment: I had a whole answer ready to go, but then I realized it's not entirely useful, so here's a comment instead. The [ב"ח](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Sirkis) is technically a commentary on the Tur, but he comments on the B"Y a bit. In addition, the [Perishah/Derishah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk) are also technically commentaries on the Tur, but they (the Derishah in particular) address questions in the Tur, often raised by the B"Y.